# pipes in Visual Studio build events

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, batch-file, pipe

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition with SP1.

I have a Pre-Link Event which needs to invoke one program and send its output to another.

```
foo | bar
```

This command works as expected when invoked from a command line or batch file. The command fails when invoked from the Pre-Link Event (even if the Pre-Link Event invokes a separate batch file containing the command). 'foo' runs and produces output which appears in Visual Studio, but this output is not fed to 'bar', and in fact it appears 'bar' is never invoked at all. Even when the Pre-Link Event invokes CMD or NMAKE which in turn invokes the piped commands, only 'foo' runs.

Is Visual Studio broken and/or is there some arcane ritual I can perform to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410029/how-do-i-pipe-output-when-debugging-in-visual-studio-2008) for the > operator. I suspect the same thing may be happening with pipes.

Comment: It appears that answer applies to VS2008 only. One poster says the '>' operator works fine in VS2005.