# Output in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

i am a new programmer in visual studio (using the 2008 version)

i have 2 questions.. maybe someone can help me with them..

1. when running my program, it prints allot of things, it opens the cmd windos, and then closes it right away. how do i get that window to stay open and not close?
2. i want to save the out put to a file. i want to redirect the output from the program automaticly into a txt file. how do i do that?
   i know that i can do it through the cmd window using sone kind of '<' command .. but i need to use visual studios compiler (not gcc/g++) is there a way to get the output to a file?

Comment: Everyone's answered your first question, but ignored the second. You'll find the answer here: [How do I pipe output when debugging in Visual Studio 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410029/how-do-i-pipe-output-when-debugging-in-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the first question, I myself had trouble with that. I don't have a real solution, but I simply put:

```
int a;
cin >> a;
```

at the end of the program, thus causing the window not to close until I type a number.

Answer (score 4):

1) There is no IDE option for that. You have to add `system("pause");` or `cin.get();` in the end of your `main`.

Comment: Because breakpoints only hit when the debugger is attached. If you want to debug your program without the debugger, you'd be out of luck.

Comment: @juergen that's an option too, but then you must run with Debugging.

Comment: Can't you use Ctrl+F5 to run with pause from the IDE?

Comment: Ctrl+F5 runs without attaching the debugger. It's merely a side-effect of that behavior that it pauses at the end of execution, not a feature.